# Failed to generate BR when moving application to lilbrary

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding, android-library

I have already made one application now I want to migrate it to the library and use it as **.aar** in other project's, but when I tried to migrate it to the library by changing the plugin to the library and removed applicationid I am not able to generate **BR** reference for data binding. Here is my Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {

compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
}

flavorDimensions "version"

productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "version"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_IDProof", "true"
        buildConfigField 'int', 'APP_TYPE', '2'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_GALLERY_OPTION", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_MULTIPLE_PRODUCT", "false"
    }
    uat {
        dimension "version"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_IDProof", "true"
        buildConfigField 'int', 'APP_TYPE', '2'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_GALLERY_OPTION", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_MULTIPLE_PRODUCT", "false"
    }
    production {
        dimension "version"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_IDProof", "false"
        buildConfigField 'int', 'APP_TYPE', '2'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_GALLERY_OPTION", "false"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "ALLOW_MULTIPLE_PRODUCT", "false"
    }
} }



dependencies {
def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'

implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'


implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation('com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0') { transitive = false }
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.Gavras:MultiLineRadioGroup:v1.0.0.6'
implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'

implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.2.2'

implementation 'com.nex3z:toggle-button-group:1.2.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'}
```

I am using **androidx** could that be the reason here? Please let me know if anything missing this is the process of migrating the application to the library.

Comment: Is the `app` module which you imported your library also using `dataBinding { enabled = true }`?

Comment: yes it is also using databinding @wonsuc